# Query returns different (no) results when using a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have two select queries returning different results as follows:

This query returns 29 rows:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `last`,`first`,`mate`,`address`
  FROM `homeownersnew` 
 WHERE `last` LIKE "s%" AND 
       `address` != "" 
 LIMIT ' . (($pagination->get_page() - 1) * $records_per_page) . ', ' . $records_per_page . '';
```

This query uses a variable to attempt to accomplish the same results but returns 0 rows:

```
@$last = "s%";

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `last`,`first`,`mate`,`address`
  FROM `homeownersnew` 
 WHERE `last` LIKE "$last" AND 
       `address` != "" 
 LIMIT ' . (($pagination->get_page() - 1) * $records_per_page) . ', ' . $records_per_page . '';
```

I'm sure I am overlooking something but am unable to find the problem.

Comment: @Darren be careful when changing the content of the question when editing it, as it may give a different meaning to the question itself or potential answers.

Comment: Make sure to include the *actual* and *syntactically valid* code used.

Comment: @Prix Apologies, thanks for picking that one up! Too early in the morning here :(

Answer (score 0):

['single quoted strings are *not* interpolated'](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

> The most important feature of double-quoted strings [that is *not* found in single-quote strings] is the fact that variable names will be expanded. See string parsing for details.

Consider this trivial example which shows the issue, mainly that the query *literally* used `LIKE "$last"`:

```
$hello = "world";
echo "Hello $hello!"; // => Hello world!
echo 'Hello $hello!'; // => Hello $hello!
```

The *correct solution* in this case is to [*use parameterized queries*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2864740). It solves the string interpolation issue, cleans up the code, and prevents SQL injection or unexpected data from corrupting queries.